# How do I connect a new Lutron sensing switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I'm changing a light switch to motion sensor switch. I have 2 black wires coming from power source (only 1 is hot), and 1 black wire is going to light.
The whites (neutrals) are tied in together bypassing switch.  I know to leave these alone.

How do I tie these in to a Lutron sensing switch?
The switch has 2 black wires, 
1 green (ground)  I understand these
1 blue labeled as traveler.
1 extra wire that is alone and appears to be a connector if needed.

Allow me to label the black wires at the junction box.
A. is black HOT
B. is black (not hot) also coming into the box from the bottom separate from hot.
C. is black going to lights.

Comment: Big Luke welcome to stack exchange. Could you give us the model of motion sensor. Most of the ones I have wired require a neutral and hot to work then the 3rd wire is the switched leg. if we have the model # we can point you in the correct direction. (I know they make some that do not require a neutral).

Comment: Can you get us a photo of the junction box?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've installed the switch you are talking about before.

- Blue wire (traveler) is for 3-way applications, just cap it off
- Green wire (ground) ties in to the exposed copper wire of your Romex, or into the box if you have BX cable
- Black wires: because you are using AC current, the switch doesn't really care which side of the circuit is truly 'hot'.  You just need to tie in one of them to a hot wire (A), and the other to the light(C).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short video from [lutron](http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Pages/Sensors/Sensors.aspx#installLinkTarget) showing how to install. I think it is the same as what you have.

Comment: Ed, link-only answers are frowned upon at SE sites--if the link dies the answer dies with it. It would be better to summarize the solution here and include the link as a reference. http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers